# Skype 4.2 не сохраняет настройки и не запоминает пароль

Tags: ubuntu

Я предпологаю, что это проблема возникает из за прав доступа. Как можно скайпу дать права суперпользователя?

Comment: Это самоубийство. Программам не нужно давать права суперпользователя.

Answer (score 1):

Права выдаются не программам а пользователям, от имени которых они запускаются. Что-бы решить вашу задачу, соответственно, надо запустить скайп от пользователя root, но это очень плохая идея - прикладной софт не должен работать от рута. Я советую попробовать запустить скайп из консоли, от вашего пользователя, возможно, по ругани в консоли вы поймете в чем причина несохранения. Если это не поможет прояснить ситуацию - смотрите системные журналы на предмет ошибок.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение. В моём случае нужно было удалить скрытую /.Skype в каталоге ~